# How to connect to a remote sqlite database in r

Tags: mysql, r, sqlite

I am not familiar SQLite. So I wonder if I can fetch SQLite data from a remote server?

I know I can do this quite easily with MySQL data,

```
# Load package.
library("RMySQL")

# MySQL connection.
DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="root", password="xxx", host="127.0.0.1", db="xxxx")

# Select data from a table.
data = dbGetQuery(DB, "SELECT * FROM article")
```

But for SQLite, it seems that it requires a path,

```
# Load package.
library("RSQLite")

# Connect to the sqlite file.
DB <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "C:/SQLite/xxxx.sqlite")
```

How can I know and obtain the path of a remote server then? Can I do this below?

```
http://mywebsite-name.com/sqlite/xxxx.sqlite
```

Comment: Unless `mywebsite-name.com` provides random-access to the file, I don't think you can. The monolithic nature of SQLite would require HTTP-based random-access to the file (I don't know if/how to do that). Perhaps download it to a temporary directory first and query it locally?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the tips. how can I `download it to a temporary directory first`? What r syntax for download a .sqlite database?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can (though I hope somebody will help me if I'm wrong, or perhaps you could raise an [issue](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues) on the package [github site](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite)).

As I started to comment, download it first and operate on it as a local file. There are several ways to download files like this, but the most direct is likely with `download.file`.

If you want to download it and keep it around, set `dbfile` to be something in a known location (perhaps the current working directory. However, if keeping it around is not critical and/or you want to generalize this and not have various sqlite files sitting around, you can download them to a temporary location:

```
dbfile <- tempfile(fileext=".sqlite") # not created yet, just a string
```

To download, simply:

```
download.file("http://mywebsite-name.com/xxxx.sqlite", dbfile)
```

And then SQL away ...

```
library(RSQLite)
DB <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=dbfile)
## ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. so I must know where the .sqlite file is so that i can use this line `download.file("http://mywebsite-name.com/xxxx.sqlite", dbfile)`, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you'll need to do some scraping and/or other techniques to determine the true URL. Perhaps something like the `rvest` package can help with scraping.